# Lightbox wrong visual display on responsive design

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, lightbox

I have a site with an image lightbox gallery. Here's the url: https://blog.jazierkasimcak.sk/?galleries=filtracia-rozhanovce

When I open this site on mobile device (tablet etc.) after clicking the image, a modal goes wrong. The image exceeds the device's display and it looks terrible. I searched there's something wrong in CSS, but I found nothing in last three hours. 
The width of image is more than 1000px, but the display width is only 320px. I really don't know why.

There are some widths and heights, probably calculated by javascript, but they are calculated wrong. The site is powered by WordPress and template UPLIFT with swift builder tool.

If anyone could help me, I would be thankful

Comment: I just tested this, and it worked just fine for me.  This is probably a device specific issue like using the off-brand browsers that come on certain phones, or you have strict security settings on your phone like no javascript.  Since this will only impact certain customers, my suggestion is to contact the developer of the plugin and report which device/browser it does not work on and patch it when they release a fix.  If you are really concerned about it, you could try using a different plugin.

Comment: Hmmm, I used google chrome on mobile. I have some kind of Huawei. The wrong display is also in webmaster tools in desktop google chrome (F12 then switch to responsive display and set width f.e.320px). Here's the screenshot with wrong image which can I see on mobile https://snag.gy/Gj5l4a.jpg

Comment: The issue is likely with you screen size emulator. Try just putting your browser into windowed mode and making it smaller like the size of a mobile device and see if it works.

Comment: It looks like the plugin uses JS to reset image sizes instead of using dynamic CSS rules.  This causes issues when you try to load it as a box inside of a larger window if the JS is pulling the window size to base things off of.

Comment: IE: why Google's screen size emulator will fail.  Not sure why your Huawei would have issues too unless it's browser does not support screen size checks for JS.

Comment: @Nosajimiki how can I fix that? I supposed there's something wrong with meta viewport. But this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1"/> seems to be OK

Comment: Report the problem to the developer of the lightbox, or install a different plugin.  If this was a CSS problem, it would normally be pretty easy to override with your own CSS, but since it's a JS problem, you are better off not messing with it.  Even if you modified the plugin itself to work differently, it would mean that you could no longer install future patches.  That would raise a security risk to your site because if anyone were to ever discover an exploit in that plugin, you could not install the fix without over writing your own work.

Answer (score 0):

after 4 hours I found an error. There was width of footer set to 1170px !important, so lightbox thought, that it has a place to display very big image. That was coded by another coder, not by me.